# c# detect if the system supports opencl

Tags: c#, system, opencl, detection, system-information

I want to detect if a system supports `opencl` or not. I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. I'm also no looking for any extra libraries to use because my c# code doesn't need to actually USE `opencl` but just know if the system `CAN` use `opencl` or if the support is there atleast. Thanks.

Also I've use `ManagementObjectSearcher` and looked in `Win32_VideoController` but theres no mentioning of it that I see via that method.

Comment: have you read any of the articles on Open CL and what it is and or does..? [OpenCL](http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/opencl-zone/)

Comment: Yes I know of opencl im just looking for a way in c# to detect if opencl is installed. maybe by detecting if AMD APP SDK is installed or something. I'm not sure what the best way to detect opencl support on a system would be. the amd app sdk option wouldn't be the best route as new intel chipsets support opencl as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .Net binding for OpenCL (http://openclnet.codeplex.com/) which would allow to list all available OpenCL devices in your system and check if one of them has the features you need.

Any simple "Getting Started with OpenCL" like article will gove you the required calls to get the above list. For example this article: http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/

Alternatively you can create a simple C/C++ library and call native from .Net code to check what you need.

Hope that helps.